# DRF: data structure in serializer or view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Given the models below, I've been trying to figure out how to return the data structure I have in mind (also below) using Django REST Framework.

How would this be accomplished within a serializer, or does such a data structure need to be built within a view using traditional Django-style queries?

**About**

Basically, a word is created, users submit definitions for that word, and vote on each definition (funniest, saddest, wtf, etc.)

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Word(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    word = models.CharField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()


class Definition(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    word = models.ForeignKey(Word, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    definition = models.CharField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()


class Vote_category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField()


class Vote_history(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    definition = models.ForeignKey(Definition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    vote = models.ForeignKey(Vote_category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Expected Query Result Structure**

```
word: 'hello',
definitions: [
    {
        user: 'alice',
        definition: 'an expression of greeting',
        votes: {
            funny: 3,
            sad: 1,
            wtf: 7
        },
        votes_total: 11
    },
    etc...
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: definitions should be a `list` not a `dict`, shouldn't they ?

Comment: @Michael : good catch. I updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

The schema you attached can (and should) be generated using Django REST Framework Serializers; the nested elements of your schema can be generated using nested serializers. Generally these serializers will inherit from the `ModelSerializer`.

Here is an example of the nested serializers you would use to begin to construct your schema:

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for a Word"""
    definitions = DefinitionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = ('word', 'definitions')

class DefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for a Definition"""
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    votes = VoteSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = ('definition', 'user', 'votes')
```

One part of the schema you have listed which may be more complicated is the map of vote category to vote count.  DRF naturally would create a structure which is a list of objects rather than a single object as your schema has.  To override that behavior you could look into [creating a custom ListSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior).

Comment: thanks. Indeed, the map of vote category to vote count is the most complicated part. Everything else I have working. Help is welcomed.

Comment: If it's not completely necessary that it be encoded in a single JSON `object`, you can represent it as a list of `objects` with one property to represent the type of vote (i.e. `funny`, `sad` etc.) and another property to represent the count.  That was my solution to this same problem.  If the answer has solved your issue, you can accept it so that others know your question has been answered. Hope it helps!